# How do I Open my DNS to the world?

Tags: dns, centos, domain, bind

So, I configured BIND on 2 of my servers. I have BIND fully working. I changed my DNS on my Computer to my master server. I then visited the domain I setup. it seems to work. but once I'm not connected using my DNS it does not work. Is there some place on the internet where I have to submit my name-servers?

Sorry for such a noob question. I have searched the internet for hours and could not find anything.

I'm new at hosting my own DNS and domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgive me - but as an old timer - if you are asking these questions you are not ready to put your nameservers on the Internet.   Maybe you should acquire a copy of "DNS and BIND in a Nutshell", go through it and then, once you understand it fully, put your DNS online.  (My fear is, if you put your nameservers online you are opening yourself and others to a DOS / DOS amplification attack).

**The answer below should be considered an overview for academic purposes - until you have a full understanding I would strongly caution against proceeding.**

In order to get your nameservers working for the wider Internet, you need at least 2 nameservers.  Once you have your records set up, you need to go the the registrar for the domain names and put in your NS records.  Sometimes its adequate to put in your NS records and IP addresses, other times you will need to ask your ISP to add "Glue" records.   There is no "registration process" required, but Glue records are special records which need to be added into the TLD/CCTLD/equivalent (ie parent) nameservers when your domain name is authorative for itself - its basically telling the parent nameserver where to start looking for your domains.

You also want to make sure that your nameserver is answering requests coming from the wider Internet.  This may require changes to your firewalls and / or allowing port 53 (BOTH UDP AND TCP) to pass from your external address to your LAN.

You need to make sure that (for external hosts) your nameservers answer authoratively only [ ie they don't answer for google.com or other domain names ] otherwise your nameservers will be co-opted in a DOS amplification attack.   You may also need to run SPLIT DNS (and on the LAN side, authoritative  and recursive DNS if you are behind NAT and are using your DNS servers.

Comment: everything you said I basically have configured I also made sure that I'm not vulnerable to DoS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you register the domain you are trying to setup?  You need to login to your [registrar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registrar) and have them delegate that domain to your servers.

Comment: I'm trying to host my own domain on my own nameservers using my own DNS.

Comment: And I got it to work but not if you don't have my DNS IP added into your device manually.

Comment: You can't just randomly pick your own name and use it.  You  need to register (pay $$$) for the privilege to have a name, if you want it to be usable globally.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. that's kind of disappointing though.